# Android development specifics

Tags: android, mobile-application

I am looking into mobile app development, and I had some questions about the android platform.

1. Does the android platform use a central settings and preferences page (much like the gears icon on an iOS device)?
2. I've been reading about services.  Are these what I would use if I wanted to develop an application that doesn't have a UI (think something like the drop box client)?
3. In my reading about services I read that the android OS will kill your service when it thinks that it needs to reclaim resources.  Is there a way to ensure a service wouldn't be killed?
4. How much control would I as a developer have over the physical hardware?  Say if I wanted to make an app to block distractions, and to do this I would need to control the networking interfaces beyond purposely misconfiguring these interfaces to block their connection?  Can I programmatically turn off these interfaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Each individual application has its own settings page, but this is generally created by using the built-in Android settings class (you can just subclass `PreferenceActivity`)
2. Every application must have an [activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html) (A screen with a UI), but yes, you can do the majority of your work in a service, which is analogous to a background process on a desktop computer
3. There is no way to ensure that Android won't kill your service without rooting the phone.  However,

> "If the service is bound to an activity that has user focus, then it's
>   less likely to be killed, and if the service is declared to run in the
>   foreground (discussed later), then it will almost never be killed" <sup>[link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html)</sup>

1. Yes, you have access to any hardware (GPS, WiFi, Bluetooth, 3G radios, camera, etc) through the [Android API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/package-summary.html).  You will have to request an install time permission from the user in order to deal with them, however.  Also, other programs can turn them back on.